# What's the best way to add support for multiple languages in an app?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, multilingual

I'm looking for a way to include multilingual support in an app I'm working on for Android Honeycomb - what's the best practise of doing this?

I've been looking at .mo files and such, but haven't been able to find a concrete answer just yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try localozation

Tutorial is here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at [this](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/):

Shouldn't have changed much in Honeycomb

Comment: Thanks Jasalguero! Accepted the other answer as he was quicker and it was a direct link to the developer documentation, but your help is much appreciated as well :)